# Local client HTTP proxy for monitoring and filtering

Tags: proxy, http-proxy

What is a robust open source local client HTTP proxy for monitoring and filtering?

The ideal proxy could be scripted and interfaced with at run time.

[UPDATE] A proxy that runs on the client machine and all browsing runs through that proxy

Thanks

Comment: Can you expand on your question a bit. What do you mean by 'local client http proxy'? Do you mean a proxy that runs on the client machine and all browsing runs through that proxy? Or do you mean a Proxy server that requires a fat client to work (i.e. Novell Bordermanager of yore)? 

What exactally are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

[Apache and mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_proxy.html)

Comment: To clarify, is this a proxy that runs on the client machine and all browsing runs through that proxy?

Comment: Sure, you can run it locally.

Answer (score 0):

So ... i guess you could run squid on the local machine and force all traffic through that. BUT there really isn't a whole lot you can do to stop someone from just not using that proxy and still getting to the web since the proxy server NEEDS to be allowed to access the internet.

I ask again - what are you trying to accomplish? We can probably give you better answers without knowing the end goal (like a proxy may not be the best solution).

I'm tempted to vote this to SuperUser as it reads like you are looking for a parental control type solution which you would probably get a better response from the people over there.

Comment: The end goal is to create a self moderation tool.  It helps you keep track of time spent on addicting sites, set goals, and warn you if you exceed your goal.

Comment: I appreciate that SuperUser will be aware of NetNanny, BlueCoat/K9 style solutions; but I feel that Server administrators know proxies - and with some imagination we could move it to the client machine.

Comment: I'm looking for a robust proxy that I can script

Answer (score 0):

It's a product. But Komodo IDE (a development environment for a bunch of dynamic languages) does what you're looking for. There's a component built in called HTTP Inspector, you set your application to use it as a proxy (localhost:8080) all traffic runs through it, and you can set up rules to manipulate traffic on the fly. http://activestate.com

I haven't used it myself, but I've heard good things about fiddler: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Fiddler2 and portswigger's Burp Proxy.